# Image Processing: How to detect borders of a bill in an image

Tags: python

I'm working on Python 2.7, using the OpenCV library. I am trying to find automatically make the edges of the bill and to crop it at the right (rectangular) size, here is one example:

[image]

Comment: Look for Canny edge detection opencv

Comment: First you have to improve the image, then you can use the Canny edge detection like mentioned by Joe. You have to take a look to openCV library.

Answer (score 0):

What you have asked is too general and difficult to do it perfectly (Due to curved edges , and bad white balance in the picture). The basic try in edge detection can be done with Canny Edge detection.

But the bill does not have exact rectangular edge , and the paper is bent.
The best way you can develop a solution is to make a [Camscanner](https://github.com/mukyasa/MMCamScanner) like application , which uses OpenCV in it.